# Django urls.py bug - some patterns not working

Tags: python, django, web

I've encountered a one nasty bug in my code while developing a personal blog in Django. Basically, I've changed my urls.py file by adding a couple of rules to make certain views accessible.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'blogas.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),

]
```

Everything seems to be working except when I try access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`about or /posts, Django throws out a 404 error. What is the reason of this? I've defined both rules but the system seems not to recognize the pattern - maybe I've mispelled something? Maybe I know nothing about url formatting (could be, it's my first time doing this stuff)?

A big thanks from a newbie programmer to everyone who finds the bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change position of `url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post'),`.

```
 urlpatterns = [
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'blogas.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
        url(r'^posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post'),
        ]
```

urlpatterns is list and order of urls is important.

Comment: Thank you for the solution yet it seems page is only reachable with a slash. Without one, it still shows me 404. How do I get around this?

Comment: Try this `url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post')`

Comment: I don't know why, but it works! Maybe a little explanation? :D

Answer (score 5):

The url-patterns are processed from top to bottom. Your third pattern `^(?P<slug>\w+)` consumes everything, so `about` and `posts` is never reached.

An example: Django wants to find the view for the url `about/`. The patterns `^admin/` and `^$` do not match. But `^(?P<slug>\w+)` does, because `about` starts with letters or numbers (the character sets contained in `\w`)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('^(?P<slug>\w+)', 'about/')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b5b7be8>
```

So Django found a match, callBs `views.view_post` and finishes the request. That means, the more specific rule must come first. Better: avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Still, I want to know why they are never reached (the mechanics behind this phenomenon) so I could tackle this problem easier in the future.